# How can I sort mongodb regex search query results based on regex match count

Tags: regex, mongodb, search

I can't figure out how to sort query results based on the "best" match.

Here's a simple example, I have a "zone" collection containing a list of city/zipcode couples.

If I search several words through the regex using the "and" keyword like that :

```
"db.zones.find({$or : [ {ville: /ROQUE/}, {ville: /ANTHERON/}] })"
```

Results won't be ordered by "best match".

What other solutions do I have for that ?

Comment: There isn't a way to order by this definition of best match. The meaning of the regex in `find` is binary - a document does or does not match. Your best options are to use text search as suggested below, or, if you return a small number of documents, manually re-sort the docs into whatever best match order you have in mind.

Comment: Even using $text search doesn't seem to be helpful in keywords match ranking... what solutions do I have except sorting array itself through code ?

Comment: $text search does rank by strength of match, it just may not be what you need. If you need a sort order that's not by fields or by text match score, you'll need to do it yourself. If you limit the returned results to 10-50, I don't think the extra time to sort would be noticeable for, say, a web application.

Comment: Anyway, I think it's a pretty common thing to sort by key words match, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using ElasticSearch search engine do this query :

```
@zones = Zone.es.search(
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          should: [
            {match: {city: search}},
            {match: {zipcode: search.to_i}}
          ]
        }
      },
      size: limit
    })
```

Where search is a search param sent by view.

[ElasticSearch with Selectize plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14ncS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms

```
db.zones.ensureIndex( {  'ville' : 'text' } ,{ score: {$meta:'textScore'}}) 

db.zones.find(
   { $text: { $search: "ROQUE ANTHERON"}},
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547c2473371ea419f07b954c"),
    "ville" : "ANTHERON",
    "score" : 1.1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547c246f371ea419f07b954b"),
    "ville" : "ROQUE",
    "score" : 1
}
```

From documentation

> If the search string is a space-delimited string, $text operator
>   performs a logical OR search on each term and returns documents that
>   contains any of the terms.

You have to use mongodb 2.6

Comment: Looks like in your case the text "ROQUES" is returned before "LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON".

Comment: May be it's a normal behavior - but then my question will be how can I make sure in this case, "LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON" is returned before "ROQUES"...

Comment: @user3559701 I don't know if is the way, but if you search `db.zones.find(
   { $text: { $search: "LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON"}},
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )`

The score is 2 and you find it first Roques.. Let me know :)

Comment: That's right but logically, if I search "ROQUE" and "ANTHERON" I should get first "LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON" ? (highlier scored than the others) but thank you for your proposal :)

Comment: if you search `db.zones.find( { $text: { $search: "LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON"}}, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )`, you find first `"LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON"` with score 2 and `ROQUES` with score 1 http://pastebin.com/8yC1FgRf, and it's right

Comment: Yes that's right. Thing is if I only search "ROQUE ANTHERON" like that `db.zones.find( { $text: { $search: "ROQUE ANTHERON"}}, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )` then "ROQUES" is scored "1" against "0.6666" for "LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON" see results - http://pastebin.com/z2t0RKhm

Comment: I replicated your collection http://pastebin.com/JyFZpyaw, With your last Query I have this result http://pastebin.com/1wU8jUEQ. And it's right because your $search is ROQUE $or ANTHERON (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms). if you search with `LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON` the result is: http://pastebin.com/heY1k0zz. Let me know :)

Comment: Allright, I get you mean ! thank you. Thing is if I have those two terms, how can I make sure "LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON" is returned before "ROQUE" ?

Comment: you have to search by `LA ROQUE-D'ANTHERON`