# MongoDB writing a query for search engine

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am trying to write a search script in MongoDB but can't figure out how to do it....The thing I wan't to do is as follows....

Lets I have a string array `XD = {"the","new","world"}`

Now i want to search string array `XD` in MongoDB document (using regex) and get the result document. For example..

```
{ _id: 1, _content: "there was a boy" }
{ _id: 2, _content: "there was a boy in a new world" }
{ _id: 3, _content: "a boy" }
{ _id: 4, _content: "there was a boy in world" }
```

now I want to get result in accordance to `_content` contains the string in string array XD

```
{ _id: 2, _content: "there was a boy in a new world", _times: 3 }
{ _id: 4, _content: "there was a boy in world", times: 2 }
{ _id: 1, _content: "there was a boy", times: 1 }
```

as first document `(_id : 2 )` contains all three `{ "the" in there, "new" as new, "world" as world }` so it got `3`

second document `(_id: 4)` only two `{ "world" as world }` so it got `2`

Comment: Have you looked at [text searching](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)? Typically words like "the" are ignored (and arguably should be) but "new" and "world" would match and rank just like you are expecting already.

Comment: its just an example......word can be anything.....and here i am trying to use regex ( like if i want to search "exam" than document containing "example" or "exammed" should return....here i am talking about aggregate function which could return these type of document

Comment: Just suggesting that maybe [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html) would be more suitable for your needs. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224225/how-can-i-sort-mongodb-regex-search-query-results-based-on-regex-match-count)

Comment: thanks.....but here i also wanted to know that which document contains how many of string in string array, so that i can ranked them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do.

**Create a Regex to be matched with `_content`**

```
XD = ["the","new","world"];
regex = new RegExp(XD.join("|"), "g");
```

**Store a JS function on the server, which matches the `_content` with `XD` and returns the counts matched**

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id: "findMatchCount",
     value : function(str, regexStr) {
        XD = ["the","new","world"];
        var matches = str.match(regexStr);
        return (matches !== null) ? matches.length : 0;
     }
   }
)
```

**Use the function with `mapReduce`**

```
db.test.mapReduce(
    function(regex) {
       emit(this._id, findMatchCount(this._content, regex));
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return values;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 0 } }
);
```

This will produce the output as below:

```
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "value" : 1
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 1,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 4,
        "emit" : 4,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 4
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I am not sure how efficient this solution is but it works.

Hope this helps.